# Add smoothed curves to plot using loess()

Tags: r, time-series, loess

I have monthly data from this package: boston, and I did a timeserie

```
install.packages("fma")
library(fma)
data(package="fma")
View(boston)
timeseries<-ts(boston,start=1)
plot(timeseries)
```

Now I want to add to this plot two smoothed curves by using local polynomial regression fitting. I was using `loess()`, but something must be wrong because it gives me error. This is the code that I am using:

```
index<-1:nrow(boston)
loess(timeseries ~ index, data = boston, span = 0.8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you wish something like this?

I used `{ggplot2}` for the plots. `geom_smooth()` allows the use of `loess` with `span` argument - assuming you want to use `loess`.

For the arrangement of the plots, i.e., stacked + one x-axis, I used `{grid}`:

```r
# install.packages("fma")
library(fma)
#> Loading required package: forecast
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
timeseries <- ts(boston, start = 1)
# plot(timeseries)

library(ggplot2)
df <- as.data.frame(timeseries)
df$index <- 1:35

p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = index, y = nyase)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'loess', formula = y~x, span = 0.8) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = index, y = bse)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'loess', formula = y~x, span = 0.8) +
  theme_minimal()

grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2), size = "last"))
```

gives

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can avoid displaying confidence interval around smooth by
adding the argument `se = FALSE` to `geom_smooth()`.

---

A short correction on your line `loess(...)`, you need to specify the column of your `timeseries` object to allow regression, i. e.

```
loess(timeseries[, 1] ~ index, data = boston, span = 0.8)
# or 
loess(timeseries[, 2] ~ index, data = boston, span = 0.8)
```

Instead of 1 and 2 you could also use `"bse"` and `"nyase"`. Then, for `"bse"`:

```
index <- 1:35
a <- loess(timeseries[, "bse"] ~ index, data = boston, span = 0.8)

plot(index, timeseries[, "bse"], type = "l")
lines(predict(a), col = "blue")
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time, it is exactly what I was looking for @Pax

Comment: I was trying to mark your answer as useful but it says I need 15 reputation to vote, as soon as i get I do it! But thanks anyway

Comment: I wanted to ask you, regarding my exercise how does loess() treat outliers? and if it does it at all.